# Yii2 - Maintain values input when close Modal

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal

in one page i render another page with form in `bootstrap modal`, when fill input if close modal (not submit) only click (x) will be possible to maintain values input when open modal again?

**index,php**

```
<?= Html::a('<button class="btn btn-info">+</button>',['app/create'], ['id' => 'btn-add']) ?>


<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<div id="modal-title"></div>',
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false],
]);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
?>
```

**.js**

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-add', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
         $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

Comment: did the answer helped you solve the problem?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam good, sorry for the delay, but other priorities emerged in my project, but I already tested and works thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it works. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jquery `.load()` method to load the form inside the modal window and no matter you click the close on modal button or the overlay background when you will click the button `+` again you will load the content again inside the modal window.

So if you really want to do that you will have to move the form inside the same view where you have the `Modal` code, means you will have to add the form inline and change the button javascript to just `$('#modal').modal('show')`. It should be like below

```
<?= Html::a('<button class="btn btn-info">+</button>','#', ['id' => 'btn-add']) ?>


<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<div id="modal-title"></div>',
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false],
]);?>

<div id='modalContent'>
<?php
//your active form starts here 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => 'your-form-id',
            'action' => Url::to(['/controller/action'])

        ]
    );
?>
<?php
       ActiveForm::end();
?>
</div>

<?php Modal::end();
?>
```

and your Js should be simply

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```